# SSRS report parameters not part of query

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report, based off a stored procedure, it's working fine.  What I am looking to do is pass in a separate report level parameter, in addition to the store procedure parameters, which does nothing more that set certain text fields to visible/not visible based on this new parameter, and the like.  Problem is, I add the report level parameter, and it seems to expect it to be passed into the stored proc along with the actual stored proc parameters.  i want it to be independent of the stored proc.

What do I need to do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be totally doable.   Below is a screen shot of a report where I have three parameters and only two passed to the stored procedure:
[image]

The datadump parameter is used for formatting.
So, if you have too many parameters passed, go to the dataset.  Place your cursor on the line with the extra parameter and click delete (which will become a visible option once you click on the parameter line)

Answer (score 1):

In the dataset properties, you can set **Filter** expressions that would be used on the results of the stored procedure. The stored procedure would return all results then the SSRS report server would filter the data based on the **Filter** tab.

When you use the **Parameters** tab, it wants to map the parameters directly to parameters in the stored procedure.

[image]